# Nonlinear DE and Numerical System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to investigate nonlinear system numerical methods. For the nonlinear DE x' = 2t(1+x^2). Use the value tan(1) = 1.557407724654....

a) how to find the explicit solution $x(t)$ satisfying $x(0) = 1$?

b) how to use Euler's method to approx the value of $x(1) = e$ using $\Delta t = 0.1$. I.e., recursively determine $t_k$ and $x_k$ for $k = 1,...10$ with $\Delta t = 0$, starting with $t_0 = 0$ and $x_0 = 1$.

c) Repeat using $\Delta t = 0.05$

d) Again using Euler's method but reduce step size by a factor of 5, so that delta $t = 0.01$ to approx x(1)

e) Repeat parts b, c, and d with Improved euler's method using the same step sizes

f) Repeat using Runge-Kutta

g) Calculate the error in each case, since we now have 9 different approx for the value of $x(1) = e$, three for each method.

h) Calculate how the error changes as we change the step size from 0.01 to 0.05 and then from 0.05 to 0.01

**Can someone also write in the format that implicit EUler and RK 4 takes in this**  example?

Comment: This [*exact set of questions*](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367084/different-methods-and-nonlinear-systems#comment789176_367084) was done with a different DEQ. Are you saying that you couldn't do a single part of this variant with that answer? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, I'm stuck on how to get a computer calculator software to generate the values for delta t = 0.1, 0.05, and 0.01. Can you just help out with Euler's for part b,c,d and paste the output here?

Comment: Okay, I added an example of the improved Euler. The rest is up to you! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, thank you . However, when I use the software for Implicit Euler with h = 0.01, there seems to be an error. It works well with step sizes of h =0.05, and 0.10 but not 0.01, can you please explain why? If you get an answer, can you tell me what software you use? Thanks

Comment: You can try this solver and see what is happening near 1.0 from the graphic I included. I suspect that your method is getting to those values and not handling them well. See: and try your problem (you have to change variable names, but it has Euler and Improved), see http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/~senning/desolver/ and look at some of the values near 1.0 and above. Maybe your SW is blowing up because of this. Regards

Answer (score 2):

a. We are given the DEQ: $f(t, x) = x' = 2 t (1 + x^2), x(0) = \alpha = 1$.

We find the closed form solution as $\displaystyle x(t) = \tan\left(t^2 + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

b. To set up the Euler iteration, we have:

$h = \frac{b - a}{N} = 0.1$

$t_0 = a = 0$

$w_0 = \alpha = 1$

For $i = 1, 2, \ldots, N$:

$$w_i = w_{i-1} + h f(t, w) = w_{i-1} + 0.1\left(2~ t_{i-1} (1 + w_{i-1}^2)\right)$$

Generating the iterates yields:

$t_i ~~~~|~~ x_i$

$0.0 ~~|~~ 1.$

$0.1 ~~|~~ 1.$

$0.2 ~~|~~ 1.04$

$0.3 ~~|~~ 1.12326$

$0.4 ~~|~~ 1.25897$

$0.5 ~~|~~ 1.46577$

$0.6 ~~|~~ 1.78061$

$0.7 ~~|~~ 2.28109$

$0.8 ~~|~~ 3.14955$

$0.9 ~~|~~ 4.8967$

$1.0 ~~|~~ 9.39269$

Part c is just changing the step size for $t$.

Part d is just changing the step size for $t$.

Part e:

We have:

$x'(t) = f(t, x) = 2 t (x(t)^2+1), x(0) = 1$

$k_1 = h f(t_n, x_n)$

$k_2 = h f(t_n + (2 h)/3, x_n + (2 k_1)/3)$

$x_{n + 1}  =  x_n + k_1/4+(3 k_2)/4$

The iterates from this are:

$t_i ~~~~~|~~ x_i$

$0.0 ~~|~~ 1.0$

$0.1 ~~|~~ 1.02$

$0.2 ~~|~~ 1.08262$

$0.3 ~~|~~ 1.19637$

$0.4 ~~|~~ 1.37988$

$0.5 ~~|~~ 1.67285$

$0.6 ~~|~~ 2.16814$

$0.7 ~~|~~ 3.12781$

$0.8 ~~|~~ 5.5858$

$0.9 ~~|~~ 17.5821$

$1.0 ~~|~~ 467.086$

If you look at these results, things are looking shaky near the end. That is the point of this exercise.

If we look at a figure of actual versus numerical, we have:

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice step-by-step modeling...parts c and d should be doable! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I hope she gets it!!! Thx

Comment: @Amzoti, I got that x1 = 1.1, x2 = 1.241, and x3 = 1.4350081 with this form of Euler's method: xn  = xn-1 + 0.2tn-1 + 0.1xn-1^2, which matches your format. However, I got a different answer

Comment: Could you also provide the values for Implicit Euler and RK4 so I can check over my work on it? A setup/some values would be nice. Thanks

Comment: @mary: You wrote xn = xn-1 + 0.2tn-1 + 0.1xn-1^2, but I think you left out a product: $x_n = x_{n-1} + 0.1(2 t_{n-1}(1 + x_{n-1}^2))$. See the issue with your result?

Comment: Ah, thank you for catching. Also, could you please fill in for the other parts the details/setup so I can check over my work on mistakes like these I made?

Comment: Also, it should be a 1.03 instead of a 1.04 on that calculation.

Comment: @mary: It should be $x_2 = 1 + .1(2(1 + 1^2)) = 1 + .04 = 1.04$

Comment: @Amzoti, thanks. Can you please help with the parts e, f, for RK-4 and implicit euler so I can check over my work please?

Comment: @Amzoti, I am getting no result to display in Implicit Euler for delta t= 0.01, and no result to display for RK 4 for delta t=0.05, and 0.01 with numerical software. Can you please explain why that is happening? Thx

Answer (score 1):

a)$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t(1+x^2)\Rightarrow\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=2\,t\,dt$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int2\,t\,dt\Rightarrow\arctan(x)=t^2+C\Rightarrow x=\tan(t^2+C)$$
by initial condition $x(0)=1\Rightarrow C=\frac\pi4$